# Change WordPress search Permalink structure

Tags: search

Please I want to change my WordPress search permalink structure, from + as the separator to -

Example:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search/please+help+me+out

To

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search/please-help-me-out

I don't know much in WordPress coding, please gurus in the house help me out.